# Trying to Save Customer Account Causes 500 Error

Tags: admin, customer, error, save

Whenever I try to save a particular customer account the screen changes to the following:

**This page isn’t working
www.mywebsite.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500**

The developer tools shows the following error:

```
POST https://www.mywebsite.com/loginforadmin/customer/index/save/key/d30e331d956b64705194dec98ee5fb818d43ce247c0a8ad563d7184dc1fe846d/back/edit 500
submit @ /pub/static/version1589884676/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/mage/utils/misc.js:149
_save @ /pub/static/version1589884676/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_Ui/js/form/client.js:128
(anonymous) @ /pub/static/version1589884676/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/jquery.js:3417
fire @ /pub/static/version1589884676/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/jquery.js:3238
fireWith @ /pub/static/version1589884676/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/jquery.js:3368
deferred.<computed> @ /pub/static/version1589884676/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/jquery.js:3467
success @ /pub/static/version1589884676/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_Ui/js/form/client.js:46
fire @ /pub/static/version1589884676/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/jquery.js:3238
fireWith @ /pub/static/version1589884676/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/jquery.js:3368
done @ /pub/static/version1589884676/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/jquery.js:9846
callback @ /pub/static/version1589884676/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/jquery.js:10317
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
send @ /pub/static/version1589884676/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/jquery.js:10260
ajax @ /pub/static/version1589884676/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/jquery.js:9744
beforeSave @ /pub/static/version1589884676/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_Ui/js/form/client.js:35
save @ /pub/static/version1589884676/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_Ui/js/form/client.js:94
save @ /pub/static/version1589884676/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_Ui/js/form/provider.js:62
submit @ /pub/static/version1589884676/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_Ui/js/form/form.js:313
save @ /pub/static/version1589884676/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_Ui/js/form/form.js:265
dispatch @ /pub/static/version1589884676/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/jquery.js:5232
elemData.handle @ /pub/static/version1589884676/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/jquery.js:4884

/pub/static/version1589884676/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/mage/utils/misc.js:149
```

There was also the following error in the Apache logs.

```
AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getProduct() on boolean in /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Plugin/SalesRule/Model/Rule/Condition/Product.php:61\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Plugin/SalesRule/Model/Rule/Condition/Product.php(30): Magento\\ConfigurableProduct\\Plugin\\SalesRule\\Model\\Rule\\Condition\\Product->getProductToValidate(Object(Magento\\SalesRule\\Model\\Rule\\Condition\\Product\\Interceptor), Object(Magento\\Quote\\Model\\Quote\\Item))\n#1 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(121): Magento\\ConfigurableProduct\\Plugin\\SalesRule\\Model\\Rule\\Condition\\Product->beforeValidate(Object(Magento\\SalesRule\\Model\\Rule\\Condition\\Product\\Interceptor), Object(Magento\\Quote\\Model\\Quote\\Item))\n#2 /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\\SalesRule\\...\n', referer: https://www.mywebsite.com/username/customer/index/edit/id/9381/key/e48a53a414efd2fb61198dc522db1d12421858d2c22c031c94298829768e80df/
```

This only seems to be happening on a single customer account, all others seem to be fine.

Does anyone know what might be causing this error and how I can resolve it?

Thanks

Comment: First of all you have to check your error logs in apache/nginx to figure out what the problem is

Comment: Thanks, there was an error in the Apache logs. I've amended the question to include it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to clear cache, generation, remove page_cache, remove session and then run all commands and then check.

Comment: Thanks. I’ll give that a try and let you know.

Comment: Hasn't worked I'm afraid.

Comment: Try to check each third party extensions by disabling one by one and then give it a try.

Comment: Hi. This has suddenly started working again. I ran a bunch of SSL commands in putty but I'm not sure which one resolved the issue. Either way this was the only change I made to the site so I have to assume that this resolved the issue.